# What are advantages of "streaming" syntax in functional languages with for-yielding like Scala?

Tags: functional-programming, loops

In `Scala` we can print list

```
val nums = (1 to 10).toList
```

with both

```
nums.filter(_ < 4).foreach(println)
```

and

```
for {n <- nums if n< 4} println(n)
```

Are there any advantages of first syntax except ability to omit variable name in `foreach(println)`? Can we express evrything with second syntax or there are some things expressing better with first one?

Comment: I think this question is more suited for https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @nirshahar No, language design is on-topic here, and frowned upon on [so], so this question is more suitable here.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Ok! Didn't know that :)